# diagrams.net: How to avoid upside-down pin text when flipping Dual In-line IC

Tags: draw.io

How can I avoid that the pin text is flipped as well when flipping the Electrical / Logic Gates / Dual In-line IC shape? I'd like to have an IC with the notch pointing down. Note that the main IC text is NOT flipped, only the pin text ...

Example: [https://viewer.diagrams.net/?tags={}&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7ZRdT8IwFIZ%2FzS4h%2B0CCt0wUTCRRErwkZT20lXadXZHNX%2B8ZKxsTSTQxXnnxLKdvP3Z63pN6UayKO0My%2FqApSC%2F0aeFFN14YjobX%2BK2EshaGwagWmBG0loJWWIh3cKLv1J2gkHcWWq2lFVlXTHSaQmI7GjFG77vLNlp2%2F5oRBmfCIiHyXH0W1PJaDX2%2F1acgGLefJhQ5rnVCzgnV%2BxMpmnhRbLS2daSKGGRVumNZ6n23F2abvAyk9jsbivnoccquZpOevR9M1VMhN8ueO%2BWNyJ277yx26dryWIImc9%2BLxpTkHKgbEClYinGCOYBBgVslcRxgmFujt03NDgonWXWkKljVKn2QaJgRWOu%2B1EwkK0Ys5H26I3IlUilSWIkE90myBjkn6tAGxAvjNZIgFAFkgzCEIwJ5QbYIXj9WSIpoJENeEYPkCNZtvJEiW7rruGKAsVBcrHLQeIctD1qBNSUucRsGzu2yO9y3rRMcO4R%2F1TbEtStrTm4txcC5%2BgOHw3%2BHncPB7zgcDP%2FOYhy2D8Rh7uSRjSYf](https://viewer.diagrams.net/?tags=%7B%7D&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#R7ZRdT8IwFIZ%2FzS4h%2B0CCt0wUTCRRErwkZT20lXadXZHNX%2B8ZKxsTSTQxXnnxLKdvP3Z63pN6UayKO0My%2FqApSC%2F0aeFFN14YjobX%2BK2EshaGwagWmBG0loJWWIh3cKLv1J2gkHcWWq2lFVlXTHSaQmI7GjFG77vLNlp2%2F5oRBmfCIiHyXH0W1PJaDX2%2F1acgGLefJhQ5rnVCzgnV%2BxMpmnhRbLS2daSKGGRVumNZ6n23F2abvAyk9jsbivnoccquZpOevR9M1VMhN8ueO%2BWNyJ277yx26dryWIImc9%2BLxpTkHKgbEClYinGCOYBBgVslcRxgmFujt03NDgonWXWkKljVKn2QaJgRWOu%2B1EwkK0Ys5H26I3IlUilSWIkE90myBjkn6tAGxAvjNZIgFAFkgzCEIwJ5QbYIXj9WSIpoJENeEYPkCNZtvJEiW7rruGKAsVBcrHLQeIctD1qBNSUucRsGzu2yO9y3rRMcO4R%2F1TbEtStrTm4txcC5%2BgOHw3%2BHncPB7zgcDP%2FOYhy2D8Rh7uSRjSYf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be flipped vertically. If so, try to set Property "Starting Pin" to S.[location of Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjdbw.png)

Comment: Indeed, using the "Starting Pin" property I can get the notch to point downwards. Thanks!